# Why the initial value of the hooks cannot be given an empty object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this setProd Hooks

```
export interface faceProduct {
  readonly title: string;
  readonly prodState: string;
  readonly shipping: string;
  readonly sold: string;
  readonly alt: string;
  readonly material: string;
  readonly location: string;
  readonly src: string[];
  readonly color: string[];
  readonly saiz: string[];
  readonly price: string;
}

export interface faceProductList extends faceProduct {
  readonly id: string;
  readonly to: string;
}

 const [prod, setProd] = useState<faceProductList>({});
```

I want the initial values to be an empty object.but I get error..

```
 const [prod, setProd] = useState<faceProductList>(Object);
```

everything works with what it is connected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First case

```
const [prod, setProd] = useState<faceProductList>({});
```

correctly produces error. As @Shanon Jackson mentioned, `faceProductList` type has non-optional properties so `{}` is not assignable to variable of type `faceProductList`.

If you wish to assign, make all props of `faceProductList` optional with [`Partial<>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt) type.

```
const [prod, setProd] = useState<Partial<faceProductList>>({});
```

The second case is a way to kid TS compiler

```
const [prod, setProd] = useState<faceProductList>(Object);
```

Lets look at what [`Object` is](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/87058448797597e6e8bd13ff3d8823fff5607df6/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L267).

```
declare const Object: ObjectConstructor;
```

It is constant of type `ObjectConstructor`. `ObjectConstructor` is [defined as](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/87058448797597e6e8bd13ff3d8823fff5607df6/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L152)

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    new(value?: any): Object;
    (): any;
    (value: any): any;
    // ... other members
}
```

Take a note of function signature `(): any;`. So `Object` can be function returning variable of type `any`.

Now lets look at `useState` [definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8d217f368733b640b90ffc0c8d8224746733f6cf/types/react/index.d.ts#L845)

```
function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];
```

`initialState` can be of type `S` or function returning `S`. As `Object` is also can be function but returning more general type `any` it can be used as argument when calling `useState`.

Call to `Object()` will return [new empty object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). As call signature is `() => any` it tells TS to not check types. And yes, as a result you'll get inital empty object but *without type checking*

Comment: You said without type checking.What did you mean?that the initial value of the prod can be anything on this case, an empty object. and if you use the second method. this may lead to some errors?

Comment: TS primary role is to introduce types to JS. Wne you use variable of type  `faceProductList` TS will check taht it has `id` of type `string` and doesn't have `prop1` of something else. So in any place in your program you may access `prod.id` and it will be of type `string` and have some string except `null` or `udefined`. If you use second approach you'll have `prod` with all members set to `undefined`. But TS will have no knowledge about that. You may think about this as switching back to JS in TypeScript

Answer (score 1):

Because your telling typescript "these properties have to be defined" I.E by not putting "?" on the interface key, but then not defining them its contradictory.

You cannot have all keys as required.
But then not implement them.

Hope this helps let me know if you need further information.

Comment: To tell the truth I did not understand anything.

Comment: @Squanchy in your interfaces, you do not have a question mark after property names, and this tells Typescript that those properties are required. Since the state's type is that interface, it expects the properties of your interface to always be present because that is what you specified in the interface.

Comment: Because Object constructor returns `any`-type by default.